# MVC Razor Syntax clarification

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can some one explain why the first one works but second does not work

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go to Link", "action")


@
{
Html.ActionLink("Go to Link", "action");
}
|
```

Answer (score 0):

Your encapsulating the second one in a code block. Similar to a c# code in code-behind (controllers, console app, winforms) you are not telling the compiler what to do with it. So you are just letting it run the code. It's like saying:

```
string a;
a="5";
```

The compiler doesn't know what to do with `a` next. Do you want to write it out `Console.Write(a)` in a console app? So **in MVC you need to tell the razor engine what to do with it**. By adding the magical `@` at the beginning of the html helper, you are telling the razor engine to actually write it out, the string that was generated using `ActionLink`

```
@
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Go to Link", "action");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is an expression, the second is a code block. Have a look at Haack's [quick reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)